# How To Access And Use Text In ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using Eclipse To Create android Project

In My XML (form2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lstContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/adapter_notes -->

</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

In StructNote.java

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;


public class StructNote extends Activity {

    public String  nameOfTable;
    public Integer Sort;
    public Integer intID;
    public Boolean Favorite;
    public String  title;
    public String  detail;

}
```

In adapterNote.java

```
    package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewGroup LayoutRt;
        public TextView  txtTitle;
        public TextView  txtSort;
        public TextView  txtTableName;
        public TextView  txtID;
        public TextView  txtpos;
        public EditText  txtDetail;
        public Button    btnANCopy;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleAN);
            txtSort = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSortAN);
            txtTableName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTableNameAN);
            txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIDAN);
            txtpos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtpos);
            txtDetail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetailAN);
            LayoutRt = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_Rt);
            btnANCopy = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnANCopy);
        }


        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNote> Adapter, StructNote Item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(Item.title);
            txtDetail.setText(Item.detail);
            txtSort.setText(Item.Sort.toString());
            txtTableName.setText(Item.nameOfTable);
            txtID.setText(Item.intID.toString());
            txtpos.setText("" + position);
            LayoutRt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    /*
                    Intent intent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, ActivityEdit.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
                    */
                }
            });
            btnANCopy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intentCurrent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, SecondActivity.class);
                    intentCurrent.putExtra("Pos", position);
                    G.currentActivity.finish();
                    G.currentActivity.startActivity(intentCurrent);

                    /*
                    SecondActivity sa = new SecondActivity();
                    sa.CreateNote(position);
                    */
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

For Example When I Want to Use This Method

```
public void copy(String strdata) {
    android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    clipboard.setText(strdata);
}
```

1) I Can't Place Method In Global Class As Static Method

2) Not Possible To use it in adapterNote.java
How I Can Find Position And Copy Text In Clipboard Or Do Some Things On Text With Out Moving To Other Activity ?

I Have Changed Up StructNote.java To:

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;


public class StructNote extends Activity {

    public String  nameOfTable;
    public Integer Sort;
    public Integer intID;
    public Boolean Favorite;
    public String  title;
    public String  detail;


    public void copyTHis(int myposition) {
        final StructNote note = G.notes.get(myposition);
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(note.title + "\n " + note.detail);
    }
}
```

And Also AdapterNote.java Changed To:

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter<StructNote> {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList<StructNote> array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewGroup LayoutRt;
        public TextView  txtTitle;
        public TextView  txtSort;
        public TextView  txtTableName;
        public TextView  txtID;
        public TextView  txtpos;
        public EditText  txtDetail;
        public Button    btnANCopy;


        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleAN);
            txtSort = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSortAN);
            txtTableName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTableNameAN);
            txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIDAN);
            txtpos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtpos);
            txtDetail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDetailAN);
            LayoutRt = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_Rt);
            btnANCopy = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnANCopy);
        }


        public void fill(ArrayAdapter<StructNote> Adapter, StructNote Item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(Item.title);
            txtDetail.setText(Item.detail);
            txtSort.setText(Item.Sort.toString());
            txtTableName.setText(Item.nameOfTable);
            txtID.setText(Item.intID.toString());
            txtpos.setText("" + position);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            holder.btnANCopy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    StructNote sn = (StructNote) holder.btnANCopy.getTag();
                    sn.copyTHis(position);
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But Show Me Error On(AdapterNote.java):

```
sn.copyTHis(position);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you asking. Do you want to implement onItemClickListener to access the text inside text view?

Comment: Use this method in your `ListActivity` or `ListFragment`.

Comment: Impossible To Use Method, for example "getSystemService" Not available In AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter

Comment: @artworkadシ  can i have your mail? i have been blocked to ask question! i have some problems but there is no one to help me

Comment: @Naddy  can i have your mail too?

Answer (score 0):

You have to you that kind of function :
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, final View view, int position, long id) {}

Here is a link explaining exactly what you want!

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Hope this helped! =)

Comment: Thank Man, But There Is Some Buttons In ListView That I Want To Use Them As "Copy To ClipBoard", "Update To Database" And "Share"